# Digest Auth with Zombie.js

Tags: node.js, http-authentication, digest-authentication, zombie.js, http-digest

I would like to use Zombie.js to connect to a site that uses Digest Auth.

Can I get to the http request headers from the runtime?

Or will I need to patch Zombie to add digest auth support?

Comment: Next time don't add comments to your post under the 'answers' section. You should edit the original post, put "**EDIT**" and then your comments after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that digest auth is not currently supported by Zombie.js